# AS3 add an EnterFrame event listener to a Sprite subclass

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite, movieclip, flashdevelop

I'm using AS3 with FlashDevelop

```
CustomClassA extends Sprite
```

`CustomClassB extends CustomClassA` but also needs to execute some code every frame

Is there any other way to do this, apart from making `CustomClassA` extend `MovieClip` instead of `Sprite`?

Comment: Add listener to the stage , not to your object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to create a simple example, using a dummy concept, only to explain a way how to do it. You could try something like:

```
public class CustomClassA extends Sprite
{
    public function CustomClassA() 
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        //start your code here...
    }

    public function startEnterFrame():void
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function stopEnterFrame():void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        executeSomeCodeEveryFrameMethod();
    }

    public function executeSomeCodeEveryFrameMethod():void
    {
        //your enter frame code...
    }

    public function dispose():void
    {
        stopEnterFrame();
        //garbage collection...
    }
}
```

and then, create your CustomClassB:

```
public class CustomClassB extends CustomClassA
{
    public function CustomClassB() 
    {
    }

    override public function executeSomeCodeEveryFrameMethod():void
    {
        //custom executeSomeCodeEveryFrameMethod
    }
}
```

you can test using:

```
var customClassB:CustomClassB = new CustomClassB();
customClassB.startEnterFrame();
```